# "Multiple definition of" Error in ESP-IDF

Tags: c, compiler-errors, esp32

When I compile my esp32 program, I got this multiple definition error. Can someone help me?
This is my main.c file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"
#include "esp_log.h"

static const char *TAG = "Omni-wheel";

void app_main(void)
{
    while(1){
        something();
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "%f \n", sensorData.ax);
    }
}
```

This is my test.h file.

```
#ifndef _TEST_H_
#define _TEST_H_

struct SomeData
{
    float x;
} someData;

void something(void);

#endif
```

And finally this is my test.c file.

```
#include "test.h"

void something(void){
    sensorData.ax = 35;
}
```

I looked for the solution and still not managed to solve that error.
This is the error message.

```
/home/knight/.espressif/tools/riscv32-esp-elf/esp-12.2.0_20230208/riscv32-esp-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv32-esp-elf/12.2.0/../../../../riscv32-esp-elf/bin/ld: esp-idf/main/libmain.a(test.c.obj):/home/knight/Omni-wheel/main/test.h:7: multiple definition of `someData'; esp-idf/main/libmain.a(main.c.obj):/home/knight/Omni-wheel/main/test.h:7: first defined here
```

Comment: The error message should say where the first definition was. Please post the full message.

Comment: What does it say is being defined multiple times?

Comment: Please put it in the question. Put it in a code block so the formatting will be preserved.

Comment: If your intent is to have a single global variable then [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files) explains how to do that.

Comment: I put it and edited it.

Comment: Your header defines a variable `someData` in a structure with a member `.x`. Your code in the other files references a variable `sensorData` with a member `.ax`.  It's probably a result of incomplete editing while transferring the code to SO, but the code you display should compile and produce the errors you report.  Please read about how to create MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) — the same idea by a different name).

Answer (score 3):

Your header file contains a definition, or more accurately a *tentative definition* (since it isn't explicitly initialized), of a variable of type `struct SomeData` called `someData`.  Since this header is included in multiple source files, each of those source files defines this variable.  Then when the source files are linked you get the multiple definition error.

The fact that the definition is tentative is relevant because some compilers (i.e. older versions of gcc) will merge tentative definitions in different translation units into a single object.  Not all do this however, and yours is apparently one that does not.

You want to instead *declare* the variable in the header file:

```
#ifndef _TEST_H_
#define _TEST_H_

struct SomeData
{
    float x;
};

extern struct SomeData someData;

void something(void);

#endif
```

And *define* it in exactly one .c file:

```
#include "test.h"

struct SomeData someData;

void something(void){
    someData.x = 35;
}
```

Comment: That’s a tentative definition, not a definition. It makes a difference because it would have worked by default with GCC prior to version 10. For years, there will be people following old lessons or building old code that will be encountering this, and it needs to be explained to them why this used to work and now does not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good point.  Updated to add that detail.

Comment: Where's `sensorData` defined?  Where's the member variable `ax` specified?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I solved it by changing a few code according to @dbush's answer.